# 2001 Avalon requires a lot of power to move

Tags: starting, power, rpm, avalon, vehicle-speed-sensor

From a stop, I have to press the gas pedal down and the RPMs to about 2500 in order for the car to move. The engine light has gone on, but now it's off and when I take it the mechanic, they can "feel and see" the problem but the diagnostic isn't coming up with anything.

Comment: Automatic or stick shift?

Comment: Have you or the mechanic checked the transmission fluid level and condition? Also, why have you selected the vehicle-speed-sensor tag?

Comment: I don't know if the avalon was ever offered as a manual @WeatherVane

Comment: @GdD in UK the auto is usually standard on up-market models, otherwise with manual as standard on base models and auto as an option. When I looked up Avalon (which I never heard of) it could not see which it was.

Comment: Same in reverse?

Comment: Have you checked the parking brake? Even if it's not engaged, a broken cable to a caliper or drum can cause it to clamp down. Or it could have rusted shut. Same thing could be happening with the regular brakes. I've had a caliper that didn't want to release, causing the wheel to drag for about 10 ft before it released.